# Assignment: XOR-cipher

Tags: encryption, xor

I am currently attending a IT-Security course at the Tel Aviv University and I stuck with the an assignment task.

Please **DO NOT** post the solution if you know it. But I would be very grateful for any hint that leads me to the correct result.

Task:

"Eve has managed to intercept the following messages, encrypted by Alice using a XOR cipher:

c1 = 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0

c2 = 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0

c3 = 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1

Eve suspects Alice has been using the same key to encrypt all three messages; moreover, she suspects that the third message (m3) also happens to be m1 XOR m2.

Can you find the key k and the deciphered messages m1, m2, m3?"

Thank you very much in advance for any helpful hint!

Comment: Write down the formula to obtain $c_n$ from $m_n$ and $k_n$, then apply the two special rules you have been given. See if you can figure out $k$ from that.

Comment: Thank you, Marc! At least for some seconds I felt like "I got it"..  :-/
But I am still despairing..   I hardly dare to ask, but which TWO formulas did you mean? I am aware of the m3 = m1 XOR m2 as given one, but which should be the second? 

The formulas for c should look like these, right!?

c1 = m1 XOR k
c2 = m2 XOR k
c3 = (m1 XOR m2) XOR k

Comment: Correct. Now make use of the properties of $\oplus$ to work out the rest. The two formulas you are given are $k_1 = k_2 = k_3$ and $m_3 = m_1 \oplus m_2$. These alongside the three $c_n = m_n \oplus k_n$ are enough.

Comment: Got it! Thank you, Marc! :-)    (@Maarten: Question can be closed)

Comment: Never mind, we'll keep it, or you can delete it (closing too many questions may not allow you to ask new questions after a while).

Comment: Interestingly this question asked before very recently and got a comment as a hint, too.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes here it is [Find the key of an XOR cipher with multiple messages from the same key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/80774/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka That's not so strange. We don't really answer the questions, and they are probably part of some course. Will be tricky to find dupes that way.

Comment: i still don't get how you solve this, is there a property I'm not aware of?